# Creating master data view with multiple data views

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, sql, activities

I am trying to create one master data extension for multiple different event types like clicks, bounces, opens, and etc.

Is there any documentation that leads toward this? Or if I have to join all these data extensions together after creating them separate? I have created them all separately, but just looking to join them all into one data extension.

I'll answer any questions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the views directly (e.g. `select * from _CLick`) when creating a new Data Extension, consisting of combined data from each of them. However, please be aware the Opens and Clicks contain multiple events for same email and link (i.e. if same email has been opened multiple times by same subscriber and same link clicked multiple times, this will result in multiple entries in the respective data views). You will need to select e.g. the most recent event, if you want to reduce the data to a single entry in your new master data view.

Brgds
Lukas